# Background footer image from a folder and text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a background image in my footer by adding an image from a subfolder, as well as have custom text go over the footer image. I tried to insert the footer image by `src` after the footer heading, but I end up having the image and text just be beside each other with no layer on top.

```css
footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <img src="Images/ricepaper.png" alt="">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <a id="Contact&nbsp;Us" style="color: #14ab3f"><b>Contact Us</b></a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <dd><b>City Manager</b>
            <dd><b>P.O. Box #####</b>
            <dd><b>City</b>
            <dd><b>### ###</b>
            </dd>
    </dl>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS background-image instead of that `img` element:

```
background-image: url(Images/ricepaper.png);
background-size: cover;
```

So your code becomes

```css
footer {
  background-image: url(Images/ricepaper.png);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <dl>
    <dt>
            <a id="Contact&nbsp;Us" style="color: #14ab3f"><b>Contact Us</b></a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <dd><b>City Manager</b>
            <dd><b>P.O. Box #####</b>
            <dd><b>City</b>
            <dd><b>### ###</b>
            </dd>
    </dl>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, i definitely see the way to improve from here, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background image css property for that. You can find some ideas to add background image by following this css.

```
footer { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

or by following this link:
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/